# Kotlin copy function with conditions

Tags: kotlin, copy

Is there a way to use `copy` Kotlin function and use the original object value property in case of a conditional state non verified ?
Or a similar function that does that ?

Example:

```
data class UserEntity(
    id = String,
    email = String,
    firstName = String,
    lastName = String
)

data class UserUpdate(        
    firstName = String?,
    lastName = String?
)

@Service
class UserService(userRepository: UserRepository) {

    fun update(id: String, dto: UserUpdate) = userRepository.save(
        userRepository.findById(id).copy(
            // *it* is not available as the initial object the  
            // copy function is called from.
            firstName = dto.firstName ?: it.firstName,
            // I'd like something like:
            lastName = dto.lastName ?: keepTheOriginalLastNameProperty
        )
    )

}
```

Comment: What kind of conditions are we talking about? Be more specific.

Comment: I updated my question to me more specific as you suggest.

Comment: I've responded to your EDIT but I do not know if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`takeIf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/take-if.html) function for inlining conditions. It returns `null` if the predicate is false, which lets you chain it into a `?:`.

```
firstName = dto.firstName.takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() } ?: user.firstName
```

It can be combined quite well with [`let`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html).

```
val something = other.takeIf { it.someBool }?.let { Something(it) } ?: throw Exception()
```

---

**EDIT:** as response to your edit, unfortunately the best option I see is this:

```
fun update(id: String, dto: UserUpdate) = run {
    userRepository.findById(id).let { user ->
        val firstName = dto.firstName ?: user.firstName
        val lastName = dto.lastName ?: user.lastName
        user.copy(firstName = firstName, lastName = lastName)
    }.let {
        userRepository.save(it)
    }
}
```